# What are the correct steps to make connection and communication within one Node by creating Private Network in windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private

What are the correct steps to make connection and communication within one Node by creating Private Network in windows? Installation of Geth is done in windows successfully, puppeth is also running. But whenever I try to start mining it is not working properly. There are 3 different accounts created by me. But mining is not working properly & displaying no epoch count.

startnode.cmd

```
geth --networkid 4224 --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "." --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8543" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password ./password.sec
```

Comment: If you're asking for a different configuration than yours, then you should first tell us what's yours, don't you think?

Comment: I've just configured geth in PowerShell (Windows 10), then created directory in which I've stored .json file, .cmd file and genesis details, i have also created genesis block and then 3 accounts. Now whenever I execute the file startnode.cmd it will start processing but when I open second powershell to attach to geth and start mining, the first shell reflects by only a particular line that one block is mining

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

File `NodeInit.bat` (run once, or whenever you want to delete the DB and start from zero):

```
rd /s /q data\geth
call "C:\Program Files\Geth\geth.exe" --datadir=.\data init .\genesis.json
```

File `NodeOpen.bat` (run whenever you want to start the network):

```
cmd /c "title geth & "C:\Program Files\Geth\geth.exe""  ^
    --networkid=100                                     ^
    --rpc                                               ^
    --rpcport=8545                                      ^
    --lightkdf                                          ^
    --mine                                              ^
    --etherbase=Address of account 1 (starting with 0x) ^
    --datadir=./data                                    ^
    --verbosity=2
```

File `genesis.json`:

```
{
   "config": {
      "chainId": 100,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0
   },
   "difficulty": "0",
   "gasLimit": "0x1fffffffffffff",
   "alloc": {
        "Address of account 1 (without 0x)": {"balance": "100000000000000000000000"},
        "Address of account 2 (without 0x)": {"balance": "100000000000000000000000"},
        "Address of account 3 (without 0x)": {"balance": "100000000000000000000000"}
    }
}
```

Comment: geth --networkid 4224 --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "." --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8543" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password ./password.sec

Comment: this is what i used for startnode.cmd

Comment: @Rudrika: You should put that in your question, not here.

Comment: Yess I've. putted that code in my question.

Comment: @Rudrika: Have you tried what I suggested above?

Comment: yes, there is a process running for mining, but still coinbase account has 0 balance. i've tried you given code (genesis.json).

Comment: @Rudrika: What about my GETH configuration? It is pointless to change only the genesis file. As far as I know, if you want to enable mining, then you must configure `--etherbase` as well. Also, I'm pretty sure that `--minerthreads` is not supported on GETH for Windows. And I'm pretty sure that I had to use `--lightkdf` as well. Have you tried all of these?

Comment: No, not all Conficuration, but I'll try. Did you just say that --minerthreads is not supported on Geth(windows)? Should I use --lightkdf instead --minerthreads?

Comment: @Rudrika: Have you tried the GETH configuration that I suggested or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86912/discussion-between-rudrika-and-goodvibration).